# Trouble finding two-syllable and three-syllable rhymes (or near-rhymes) for "eld" as in "field"

Tags: technique, poetry

I am using *The Complete Rhyming Dictionary*, edited by Clement Wood, as a reference as I work through a poem.

I can't tell if my search is not thorough enough or if there is a shortage of this particular rhyme I am looking for.

I have exhausted all of my options for monosyllables and words accented on the last syllable, such as:  field, wield, and repealed, etc

So, I flipped through the other two sections of the book--1) words accented on the syllable before the last (penults, feminine rhymes, double rhymes) and 2) words accented on the third syllable from the end (antepenults, and triple rhymes), and I am having trouble finding any of this particular rhyme i'm looking for. As mentioned in the title, I would be satisfied with assonance (vowel rhymes) as well.

I am certainly not looking for you to give me rhymes or to find them yourself--I am just wondering if you could indicate whether or not the rhyming words that I am after are far and few between or if I am just not looking hard enough and that there are, in fact, plenty.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using online rhyming dictionaries? You can then try different spellings of the sound, such as 'healed'. Also, how many words are you looking for? I can think of several for the word you give but I don't know if you want nouns, verbs, adjectives, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **[Datamuse API](http://www.datamuse.com/api/)** is a word-finding query engine. It's meant to be used inside apps to find words that match a given set of constraints, and that are likely in a given context.

The following link returns a list of words (organized by syllables) that rhyme with '*keeled*'.

https://api.datamuse.com/words?s&rel_rhy=keeled

The search engine needs a valid dictionary word to find a rhyme, but the results may be different when you input different words. I used 'keeled' but got slightly different results with 'field', and got no results with 'eeled' which isn't a word, I guess.

Comment: This should be very useful--thank you.  The only trouble is I have no idea how to use it! I went to api.datamuse.com/words but couldn't type anything in within the brackets

Comment: If you start with my link, and edit just the final word (after the equal sign) right in the URL address, it will give you rhymes for that word.

Comment: TIL "comfortable" doesn't have any rhymes? https://api.datamuse.com/words?s&rel_rhy=comfortable

Answer (score 1):

Here's one of my favorite websites for finding rhymes: https://www.rhymezone.com/
You can filter the results as well.

Comment: Although I think the answer could have been expanded to directly answer the question, I don't see why it was downvoted.